# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::result()

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, mysqli, fatal-error

I have tried many ways to join two tables but showing error. showing fatal error.i am beginner in CodeIgniter.

On Model my function is this

```
$quer=$this->db->select('*')->from('assign_tble')
->join('course_details','assign_tble.ccode=course_details.ccode','LEFT')
->where('assign_tble.scode',$userID);
return $quer->result();
```

while running it is showing fatal error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::result() in
>   C:\wamp\www\keitauniv\application\models\AllCourses_m.php on line 41
>   Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::result()

this is the error showing while running.

Comment: add `$quer = .... ->get();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Codeigniter error: call to undefined method ci\_db\_mysql\_driver::result()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224655/php-codeigniter-error-call-to-undefined-method-ci-db-mysql-driverresult)

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar you are right

Comment: :) thnx  .......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('*')
->from('assign_tble')
->join('course_details','assign_tble.ccode=course_details.ccode','LEFT')
->where('assign_tble.scode',$userID);

 $query = $this->db->get();         
 return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$quer=$this->db
->select('*')
->from('assign_tble')
->join('course_details','assign_tble.ccode=course_details.ccode','LEFT')
->where('assign_tble.scode',$userID)

->get(); //Getting the results ready...


return $quer->result();
```

---.---

You have to `get()` the results before using them

You can find CI `Query Builder`'s docs [Here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Omar